# How to solve leak (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, memory-leaks

I am using instrument tool to find leaks in my code.

Tool indicating 100% leak on below line.

NSArray *subviews = [[cell subviews] copy];

How to solve leak in the above piece of code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `copy` you must match it with `release`. Without more code it is difficult to accurately diagnose how to fix this issue. However, you will most likely want to do the following:

```
NSArray *subviews = [[cell subviews] copy];
...
[subviews release];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSArray *subviews = [[cell subviews] copy];

the copy action will increment your array's retain value by 1.So you have to release it.

Comment: @dilip.ajm If you appreciate the answer then accept it.